# Passing data from database containing new line breaks jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

In a VB.NET project I am dynamically building a jquery using data from a database. Some data are containing new line information which are breaking the script.

I tried replacing vbLf by "<br>" or encoding the "<br>" but none seems to work.

This is the code I am using to simulate my real life situation:

```
    Dim sString As String = "abc" & vbLf & "def" & vbLf & "ghi"
    litJS.Text = "<script>$(idHTML3).html('" & sString & "')</script>"
```

This code gives this result:

[image: This code gives this result]
<sub>(source: [corobori.com](https://www.corobori.com/sos/2019-06-08_0-00-36.jpg))</sub>

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

If appears you want to user the string `sString` as html. In that case you need `<br>`\

```
Dim sString As String = "abc<br>def<br>ghi"
```

If you want to use multiple lines in javascript you need to create a line break

```
Dim sString As String = "abc\rdef\rghi"
litJS.Text = "<script>alert('" & sString & "')</script>"
```

But why not set the text to the label directly instead of using jQuery?

```
litJS.Text = sString
```

Comment: I have tried using br but it didn't work neither 2) I do NOT want to use multiple line in javascript, that is actually what I am trying to avoid 3) This is a simulation of my real life issue where I need to dynamically create a jquery passing data from a database, that is why I can't set up the label's text directly.

Comment: Replace(sString, vbLf, "<br>") works fine. In my real life situation the issue was that I had a vbLf and a vbCr that I didn't see at first.